# Logging module to send all unsent message to another file (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am trying to **log messages to a log file and then do a shutdown on logging and send all remaining messages to a new log file**.

But, I am observing that messages are going to the previously-created log file only. How can I fix this?

Below is my code:

```
logger_name = 'create_request'
request_Create_log = Code_vars.Requests_path+'Request_creation.log'
formatter = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename=request_Create_log,filemode='a',level=logging.DEBUG,format=formatter)
req_logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
logging.shutdown()
#new logfile creation
logger_name = 'request_'+str(req_id)
formatter = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file,filemode='a',level=logging.DEBUG,format=formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`logging.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.shutdown) documentation:

> Informs the logging system to perform an orderly shutdown by flushing and closing all handlers. This should be called at application exit and **no further use of the logging system should be made after this call**.

So first, you're using it wrong if you just want to switch your handlers/config - it's not intended for that. Second, notice it says that it closes handlers, it doesn't remove them so they're still in the system. What you might want instead is to clean up the old handlers:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()  # get the root logger
handlers = logger.handlers[:]  # make a copy of the current handlers
for handler in handlers:  # go through all available handlers and...
    logger.removeHandler(handler)  # remove them
```

And then rebuild your loggers to do what you want.